# ImmutableJS: Convert List to indexed Map

Tags: immutable.js

This question is about Immutable.js library.

I have a `List<T>`, where `T` is `{name: string, id: number}`. I want to convert it to `Map<number, T>`, with `id` of `T` to the keys. Using standard method `toMap` gives me a `Map` with sequential indexes, and there is no way to hook there. And no method like `indexBy` or other. how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it with a reducer like this:

```js
function indexBy(iterable, searchKey) {
    return iterable.reduce(
        (lookup, item) => lookup.set(item.get(searchKey), item),
        Immutable.Map()
    );
}

var things = Immutable.fromJS([
    {id: 'id-1', lol: 'abc'},
    {id: 'id-2', lol: 'def'},
    {id: 'id-3', lol: 'jkl'}
]);
var thingsLookup = indexBy(things, 'id');
thingsLookup.toJS() === {
  "id-1": { "id": "id-1", "lol": "abc" },
  "id-2": { "id": "id-2", "lol": "def" },
  "id-3": { "id": "id-3", "lol": "jkl" }
};
```

Comment: thank you for this example, I was struggling with this issue for a few days